# How to make a VBA script (that runs on Command Button Click) reflect data that has changed after I saved the script?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm quite new to VBA and I don't understand what isn't working.

I have this simple code:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim Lunch As Integer
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim objEx As New Excel.Application

Set wb = objEx.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\johndoe\Desktop\Proposal.xlsm")

Lunch = wb.Sheets("Calculator").Cells(14, 4)

If Lunch > 0 Then
TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & Lunch & " lunches in the last month"
End If

End Sub
```

The code (which is a piece of bigger code), works exactly how I want, except for the fact that if the Lunch number changes (on the Calculator Sheet) after I have saved the VBA Code, and I click the CommandButton again to run the code, it doesn't reflect this new information.

If I go into the VBA Project and simply save it again, then run it by clicking the button, it works with the updated information. I don't understand what is happening or how can I fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Question: are Proposal.xlsm and the current workbook (where the button is located) the same or different? Please clarify.

Comment: I suppose you can try `Application.Calculate` right before your if statement. (This won't fix the underlying issue but can determine there is a calculation problem somewhere in your code/workbook/application).

Comment: @M.R. It's the same workbook.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs using Application.Calculate didn't work.

Comment: If they are the same, no need to re-open the file, you must use a totally different approach. I am posting the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are the same, no need to re-open the file, you must use a different approach:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim Lunch As Integer
Dim wb As Workbook


Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Lunch = wb.Sheets("Calculator").Cells(14, 4)

If Lunch > 0 Then
  TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & Lunch & " lunches in the last month"
End If

Set wb = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the explanation, I am copying it from my comment above

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I can see what I was doing wrong now. I was taking the opening code from another implementation with two workbooks.